# extends multiple system class of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to handle error on codeigniter so I need to extends both the class "CI_Controller" and "CI_Exceptions"  so how to implement it. something like below. if it's possible to handling error globally in hooks or other way for whole system?

```
class Language extends CI_Controller , CI_Exceptions{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        parent::CI_Exceptions();

    }
}
```

Comment: As PHP doesn't support extending multiple classes, you could have CI_Controller extend CI_Exceptions, then Language could extend CI_Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice [post](http://thecancerus.com/simple-way-to-add-global-exception-handling-in-codeigniter/) on how to do this using a hook.  I copied the samples from the post, but I would go there and read up on the solution to get going int the right direction.

**Hook**

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
                       'class'    => 'ExceptionHook',
                       'function' => 'SetExceptionHandler',
                       'filename' => 'ExceptionHook.php',
                       'filepath' => 'hooks'
                      );
```

**Exception Class**

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::CI_Exceptions();
    }

        public function show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
        {   
        $severity = ( ! isset($this->levels[$severity])) ? $severity : $this->levels[$severity];
        $filepath = str_replace("\\", "/", $filepath);

        // For safety reasons we do not show the full file path
        if (FALSE !== strpos($filepath, '/'))
        {
                $x = explode('/', $filepath);
            $filepath = $x[count($x)-2].'/'.end($x);
        }

        if (ob_get_level() > $this->ob_level + 1)
        {
            ob_end_flush(); 
        }
        ob_start();
        include(APPPATH.'errors/error_php'.EXT);
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $msg = 'Severity: '.$severity.'  --> '.$message. ' '.$filepath.' '.$line;

            log_message('error', $msg , TRUE);

        mail('dev-mail@example.com', 'An Error Occurred', $msg, 'From: test@example.com');  

        }

    }
```

Comment: For CI v2+ should be `parent::__parent();`.